# Keys in PHP array are not sorted numerically

Tags: php

I have a PHP array with keys that contain a year and week number like so:

```
year-week
```

Using the built in ksort function it's returning them like so:

```
ksort($array);

2011-21
2011-3
2011-44
2011-45
```

Is it possible to have them sorted numerically like so:

```
2011-3
2011-21
2011-44
2011-45
```

Comment: not with native php. there's natsort for "natural" sorting, but it works on values, not keys. you'll have to do some mangling yourself.

Comment: Pass a callback function that compares the int values of the year and then the day of each key.

Comment: Simplest way - add leading zero in week number for one-digit number: 03 instead 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get the result you want if you format them with a 2 digit week.  Something more like 2011-03.  See sprint_f().

Answer (score 15):

If you are using PHP >= 5.4 use `ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`

Comment: Thanks. By far the best answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use `uksort` to sort the keys, and in the callback use, `strnatcmp`.

```
uksort($array, function($a,$b){
    return strnatcmp($a,$b);
});
```

Comment: This is great. This allows natural sorting in PHP 5.3. `ksort` using natural sorting isn't supported until 5.4, so this is a great work-around.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$a = array_keys($myarray);

// $a now has
// array('2011-21', '2011-3', '2011-45', '2011-44');
natsort($a);
```

This prints

```
2011-3
2011-21  
2011-44
2011-45
```

You can then use the `$a` array as a reference to each element of the array that holds the data (in the example above `$myarray`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ksort` with `natural` flag. (Only PHP 5.4+ supports)

```
ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see much simpler solutions are available, but here was my initial thought:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $comp1 = explode('-', $a);
    $comp2 = explode('-', $b);
    $year1 = (int) $comp1[0];
    $year2 = (int) $comp2[0];
    $week1 = (int) $comp1[1];
    $week2 = (int) $comp2[1];

    if ($year1 == $year2 && $week1 == $week2) {
        return 0;
    } elseif ($year1 == $year2) {
        return ($week1 < $week2) ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return ($year1 < $year2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

$array = array('2011-21', '2011-3', '2011-44', '2011-45');
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```